# Flutter Dialog with custom width and no default padding

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog

I want to make a dialog with a custom width without the default horizontal paddings, I've tried adding width to the child but it does not apply.

and there is no **contentPadding** property unlike AlertDialog, so the horizontal content padding can't be removed.

how can I fix that and add a custom width to my Dialog?

**Output:**

[image]

**Code**

```
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class PathNotFoundDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const PathNotFoundDialog({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      backgroundColor: kWhiteColor,
      surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(34.0),
      ),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            SvgPicture.asset(
              "assets/icons/path_not_found_icon.svg",
              width: 28,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            Text(
              tr("errors.pathNotFound"),
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 12.0),
            Text(
              tr("errors.pathNotFoundDescription"),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12,
                color: kGreyColorTint4,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 42),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 34,
                width: 34,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: kGreyColorTint5,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(100),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/close_icon.svg"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: Looking at the code for Dialogs, it looks like it forces the content to be at least 280 pixels wide (`constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 280.0)`) and there is no option to customize it. If you want to have it smaller, you'd have to make your own custom dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

- Wrap your `Dialog` with a `Center` and then a `SizedBox`.
- Set the desired width to the `SizedBox`.
- Add a `Padding` widget below the `Dialog`.

Code:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
        child: Dialog(
          insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          backgroundColor: kWhiteColor,
          surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(34.0),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
            ...
```